# Недопонимание ООП. Область видимости

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, методы

Такой вопрос, как в теле функции(метода), класса можно не обращаться к атрибутам класса вот так:

```
class Rso:
    _username = input()
    def func():
        print(Rso._username)
```

---

А вот так:

```
class Rso:
    _username = input()
    def func():
        print(_username)
```

---

По факту мы же в теле класса, и к атрибутам мы *можем* обращаться как в теле класса)

Comment: Никак, только через имя класса. "Например, когда мы обращаемся к родителю, мы не говорим - "родитель семьи Дошираков"" - в Python только так и говорим. К атрибутам/методам объекта только через self, к атрибутам класса - только через имя класса или cls для методов с декоратором @classmethod и первым параметром cls. Зачем - затем чтобы всегда было понятно, где глобальная переменная, где локальная, а где атрибут класса/объекта ("Явное лучше, чем неявное" (с))

Comment: Точно! Спасибо, пишите в ответ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

я бы вам предложил попробовать два варианта.
Мне лично второй вариант нравится больше.

так:

```
class Rso(object):
    _username = input('Введите ваше имя: ')
    
    def func(self):
        print(self._username)

rso = Rso()
rso.func()
```

или так:

```
class Rso(object):
    def __init__(self, _username):
        super().__init__()
        self._username = _username
    
    def func(self):
        print(self._username)

username = input('Введите ваше имя: ')        
rso = Rso(username)
rso.func()
```

Comment: Я бы хотел спросить, а что если вместо self использовать cls?

Comment: @phony51 а зачем усложнять понимание кода?